# Creating unique identifier for cadastral parcels in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2.16

I would like to know what criteria I can take to create a unique identifier number for a cadastral parcel, in QGIS version 2.16

Answer (score 2):

There wasn't a deep explanation in your question, so I can only suggest using the **Add autoincremental field** algorithm from the **Processing Toolbox**: it will create a new field storing an integer value starting from `0` and with a final value equals to the total number of features, minus 1.